# SQL Trigger so that no more than 2 consecutive

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

How to make a trigger that does not allow a STAFF to teach in the same UNIT for more than 2 consecutive YEARS. I used caps for those as they are 3 attributes that I need to use. I think I know what I am supposed to do but not sure how to implement it. I was thinking if we can use a counter to count how many YEARS a STAFF has been teaching a certain UNIT and if it goes more than 2 than it raises an error but I'm stuck with implementing it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CONSECUTIVE_TEACHING
BEFORE INSERT ON TEACHING_INFORMATION
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
s_id char;
c_id char;
t_yr number;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (TEACHING_INFORMATION.STAFFID, TEACHING_INFORMATION.COURSEID, 
TEACHING_INFORMATION.YEAR)
INTO
s_id, c_id, t_yr
FROM TEACHING_INFORMATION
WHERE
```

I'm unsure what to type in the 'WHERE' part as I'm dealing with 3 variables here. Just need some clarification here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how many years this staff has taught this course in the previous two years. If the answer is two, don't allow.

```
select  count(*)
from    TEACHING_INFORMATION
into    t_yr
where   STAFFID = :new.STAFFID
    and COURSEID = :new.COURSEID
    and YEAR between :new.YEAR - 2 and :new.YEAR - 1;
```

So if the year is 2016, it will count the number of times staff taught this course between the years 2014 and 2015. That is, if the course was taught in both of the previous years, the result will be two. Unfortunately, you will probably end up instead with an exception complaining about a mutating table.

One way around that is to front the table with a view and have the app access only the view. Your trigger would then be an *instead of* trigger on the view and so would not run into the mutating table problem. If the result of the query returns 0 or 1, the view trigger would itself perform an INSERT to the table.